# Is it possible to try Windows Server 2012 with VmWare Server 5.0?

Tags: windows, vmware-server

I would like to try windows server 2012 rc using our vmware server 5.0 infrastructure. 
The problem is that i can't install it because each time, the virtual machine reboot.
Is it vmware server 5 ready for win server 2012 ?
Thanks

Comment: Any reason you try RC instaead of the RTM version that was released mid August and that just had the last staggered release done? I.e. since the weekend, IIRC, MSDN and Technet have access to it. None RTM questions generally are not liked here.

Comment: @TomTom only the RC is released on MSDN. Or, at least, I can't see RTM on my account. Though I agree that one should really wait at this point.

Comment: RTM is out in the wold ;) I downloaded my copy on the 16th.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no product called VMWare Server 5.0, the latest version is 2.0.2, perhaps you mean VMWare's vSphere/ESXi 5.0?

If so then no, there's no support *yet* as Server 2012 isn't released yet (we don't generally deal with unreleased code on serverfault either by the way), but I know that once Server 2012 is released vSphere/ESXi 5.1 will support it within days/weeks of release.

If you had meant Server 2.0.2 then I wouldn't hold out for a patch any time soon, that's not a particularly active product these days.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to run Server 2012 on ESXi5.0 although it's not supported yet. VMWare even has KB entry for this problem:

**TRY ONE OF THESE OPTIONS**
Change the virtual machine to use EFI instead of BIOS:

```
Right-click the virtual machine and click Power > Shut Down Guest.
Right-click the virtual machine and click Edit Settings.
Click the Options tab.
Click Boot Options.
Click EFI under Firmware.
Click OK. 
Power on the virtual machine.
```

Add `vmGenCounter.enable = FALSE` to the .vmx file of the virtual machine:

```
Right-click the virtual machine and click Power > Shut Down Guest.
Right-click the virtual machine and click Edit Settings.
Click the Options tab.
Under Advanced, click General.
Click Configuration Parameters.
Click Add Row.
Under name, enter vmGenCounter.enable.
Under value, enter False.
Click OK to save the changes and then close the window.
Power on the virtual machine.
```

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=2021887

Comment: Server 2012 is still only supported on Workstation 9 and Fusion 5 however.

Comment: changed my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

There's a decent article at http://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2012/02/how-to-run-windows-8-consumer-preview.html which also applies to Windows Server 2012.

The bottom line is that there are a set of patches to install first, then the rest is just configuration.

Answer (score 0):

As of March 19 2013:

> Windows 8 / Windows Server 2012 is fully supported for ESXi 5.5/5.1
>   and ESXi 5.0 Update 1, ESXi 5.0 Update 2 and ESXi 5.0 Update 3.

Per http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2006859

Also may be applicable to you:

> Windows 8 Developer Preview / Windows Server 2012 Release Candidate
>   does not boot on ESXi 5.0. To resolve this issue, you must install
>   patch ESXi500-201112001 (Patch 02):
>
> -Download and install ESXi500-201112001 (Patch 02). For more information, see VMware ESXi 5.0, Patch Release ESXi500-201112001
>   (2007680).
>   -Create a new virtual machine configured for either Windows 7 or Windows 2008 R2.
>
> -Enable 3D graphics or do not install VMware's WDDM video driver.
>
> -Install Windows 8 / Windows Server 2012 from Media.
>
> -Install VMware Tools.
>
> Note: VMware does not recommend installing VMware's WDDM video driver. Use the default VESA driver.