# Does Windows Server 2012 work on VMWare Server 2

Tags: virtual-machines, vmware-server, windows-server-2012

VMWare Server 2.0 is non longer supported by VMWare but still available 'as is'.

Is it possible to run Windows Server 2012 standard on it?

Comment: Different Q - but accepted answer gives indication of NO http://serverfault.com/questions/423803/is-it-possible-to-try-windows-server-2012-with-vmware-server-5-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer is no.
Is it possible? Probably - Anything is ***usually*** possible with enough time and effort.

Is it worth the time and effort to get it working? No - and even if you could get it mostly working, I doubt it would work all that well.

If you're looking for a free workstation level virtualization solution, why not download the free [VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) and install windows 2012 there? If you have supported hardware, why not download the free version of ESXi and install 2012 there (or Hyper-V for that matter..)

Comment: Thanks for the helpful insight that anything is usually possible - I had no idea. I'll be along in a minute to ask if its possible to run Quake on an old Nokia while sat on the moon in nothing but a tutu so you can be wise again ;)

Comment: Ha.. i did qualify it as "usually" :)